# integration of constant sets

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we are working with measurable function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $A_c = \{x \in A : f(x) = c\}$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it true that the following inequality holds:

$$\mu(A_c) * c \leq \int_{A_c} f d \mu$$

Comment: What does $u$, on the left hand side, denote? Also...isn't the value on the right-hand side a complex number? What does an inequality between complex numbers denote?

Comment: I have adjusted my answer can you check above. $\mu$ is original measure we are working with.

Comment: Why is  $A_c$ defined for complex numbers $c$, if $f$ is real-valued?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be the measure space in question. Because $f$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$ I will assume that $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, note that
\begin{align*}
\mu(A_c) c = \int_{A_c} c\,\mathrm{d}\mu = \int_{A_c} f\,\mathrm{d}\mu
\end{align*}
where we have used that $f \equiv c$ a.e. on $A_c$. In particular, we actually have equality.